# clock_gettime in Linux

Tags: c, linux

MAIN.c :

```
int sum()
{
    int x = 100, y =200, z;
    z =x;
    z=y;
    printf("value is %d", z);
    return 1;

}

int main()
{
    double starttime, stoptime;
    int a=1, b=10, c;
    starttime = GetTimeStamp();          // I am calculating time here.
    printf("start  time is %f", starttime);
    c =a;
    printf("value is %d", c);
    c =b;
    printf("value is %d", c);
    c= a+b;

        printf("value is %d", c);
        printf("value is %d", c);
        printf("value is %d", c);
        printf("value is %d", c);    

    stoptime =GetTimeStamp();    // I want to know the time here.
    printf("stop  time is %f", stoptime);
    return 0;

}
```

TIMER.c :

```
#define BILLION  1000000L
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

int GetTimeStamp()
{
struct timespec start;

//double startTime;

           // if( (startTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 )
            if((clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1 )
            {
              perror("clock gettime");

            }
         //  startTime =start.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * start.tv_nsec;  // to make it milli 


        return ((start.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * start.tv_nsec)/(double)BILLION);
}
```

timer.h :

```
#ifndef TIMESTAMP_H_
#define TIMESTAMP_H_
int GetTimeStamp();

#endif /* TIMESTAMP_H_ */
```

I want to create a free running timer and want to get the time when it start executing and also the time when it finish the execution. So I created a timer as above in TIMER.c and I am using that in main.c. I am calling the GetTimeStamp() in MAIN.c at the begging of the program and again at the end of time. The output : it is showing the same time for both starttime and stop time as 1594.0000000

Comment: You might want to check the return type of the `GetTimeStamp` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your multiplier for `tv_nsec` is wrong, and your constant `BILLION` is wrong too. The prefix `n` (nano) means 10^-9, and a billion is equal to 10^9. Change:

```
    return ((start.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * start.tv_nsec)/(double)BILLION);
```

to:

```
    return 1e9 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec;        // return ns time stamp
```

or:

```
    return 1e6 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec * 1e-3; // return µs time stamp
```

or:

```
    return 1e3 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec * 1e-6; // return ms time stamp
```

or:

```
    return start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec * 1e-9;       // return seconds time stamp
```

depending on what units you want to use for your timestamp.

As already pointed out elsewhere, you might want to use e.g. a `double` for your timestamp, rather than an `int`, since this gives you better range and resolution and it's also what you're already using in `main`.

```
double GetTimeStamp(void)
{
    ...

    return 1e9 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec;        // return ns time stamp
}
```

Comment: If I am doing the same for real time linux then can I use the same api ??

Comment: Sure - `clock_gettime` is pretty standard - the only things to watch out for are (a) not all clock types are supported on all platforms and (b) some clock types return CPU time and some return wall clock time - this can matter a lot, e.g. if you're using threads.

Comment: My situation is : slave is receiving data from the master and when the slave receives data on ethernet layer, I should calculate the timestamp (i.e time at which the data as arrived) and also to calculate the time when the kernel start executing the arrived data. So what is your suggestion for this ?? am I in the right direction ???

Comment: Yes, so long as your platform supports `CLOCK_REALTIME` (and most do) then you should be fine, since this just returns "wall clock" time.

Comment: to get the cpu time then what should i do ??

Comment: It sounds like `CLOCK_REALTIME` is what you need, but if you think you need something different then see the [man page for clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).